# Join of two tables in prestoDB based on closest value

Tags: bigdata, amazon-athena, presto

I have two tables, one with timeseries values and another one with prices. For example

**timeseries**

```
purchase_date   user_id    item_id
1618231488      123        2313
1618244875      435        2314
1618266985      23         2313
1618268671      54         144
...
```

**price**

```
item_id   price_date     price
2313      1618231400     233.67
2313      1618232400     294.12
2313      1618254400     224.14
144       1618254400     212.34
...
```

**Goal**: evaluate the price of each item purchased by a user at the given purchase timestamp.

As you can see from sample data, a purchase can happen at any timestamp, while the price of an item is stored every hour inconsistently. So, for example, we can have an item price updated every hour for one day and for the next day, maybe just a couple of updates. This happens because system records price only if there's a change.

Using an SQL query (engine is PrestoDB) and keeping in mind that the timeseries table can be of millions of rows (while the prices one up to a few hundreds thousands), how can I get a table as follows

**timeseries_with_price**

```
date          user   item   price
1618231488    123    2313   xxx.xx
1618244875    435    2314   xxx.xx
1618266985    23     2313   xxx.xx
1618268671    54     144    xxx.xx
...
```

Where xxx.xx are the prices at given timestamp. Of course, item price doesn't change linearly but change when a new record is put in database. So if I have (simplifying timestamps for readability)

- price at date 100 equal to 14.02$
- price at date 300 equal to 23.02$

These are the transactions' prices based on purchase date:

- purchase_date: 100 -> price 14.02$
- purchase_date: 148 -> price 14.02$
- purchase_date: 299 -> price 14.02$
- purchase_date: 300 -> price 23.02$
- purchase_date: 348 -> price 23.02$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do join of both tables based on `item_id` and then select only the elements that are closest in time, for example:

```
select purchase_date, 
       user_id,
       item_id,
       min_by(price, abs(purchase_date-price_date)) as price
from timeseries join price using(item_id)
group by purchase_date, user_id, item_id
```

See the docs for the `min_by` function here: https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/aggregate.html#min_by

I'm purposefully placing the price table to the right of the join since it's the smallest of the two. Ideally though, when a user makes a purchase you would keep a pointer to a unique identifier in the `price` table.

Comment: Thank you, that was a nice answer. I didn't though about joining by item_id and I didn't know about the min_by() function. Unfortunately, the query runs for more than 30 mins and terminates (timeout), basically there are too many rows for that join to complete in time.
I know the best option would be to have the price stored when the purchase is recorded, unfortunately we're in the situation where we cannot handle that part of the logs and we can only work on this structure of the data.

Comment: that's strange, millions of rows times 100 thousand rows is not particularly big for athena. What's the underlying data format? I would convert to an efficient io format like parquet or orc (can be done via a ctas query), that usually helps a lot with these kinds of performance issues.

Comment: it is parquet
How I solved it was to keep your suggestion (thanks again!), but to improve the JOIN with an "AND" clause:
`from timeseries as t left join price as p on t.item_id = p.item_id AND abs(t.purchase_date - p.price_date) < 86400`    
since for all the elements I always have at least 1 price for each day